# Stata: Elements of variable

Tags: loops, vector, stata

How can I edit every 2nd value of a variable?

My code is:

```
set obs 100
gen u = invnorm(uniform())
forvalues d = 1/50 {
gen u[2*d] = u[2*d] + 1
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 6):

The syntax for `generate` doesn't allow anything except a storage type and variable name (and a label name, irrelevant here) after `generate` and before `=`. This is clearly indicated by the help file.

You don't need a loop here. If you want to work on observations 2, 4, ... then

```
 gen new_u = u + 1 if mod(_n, 2) == 0
```

selects even observation numbers. To change an existing variable `generate` is illegal, but you could go

```
 replace u = u + 1 if mod(_n, 2) == 0
```

An abbreviation for

```
 mod(_n, 2) == 0
```

is

```
!mod(_n, 2)
```

given that the modulus (strictly, remainder) on dividing integers by 2 can only be 1 or 0, so negating zeros (logical false) gives you ones (logical true).

P.S.

```
invnorm(uniform())
```

is an ancient way to call random normal deviates with mean 0 and variance 1. In modern Statas

```
rnormal()
```

will do it.

Answer (score 4):

A one-line version of your loop would be:

`gen u = rnormal(!mod(_n,2),1)`

The logic is that you start with draws from a standard normal distribution and want to add 1 to all even observations. Adding 1 means that the mean for the distribution is 1 instead of 0. The first argument of the `rnormal()` function is the mean. So if we can feed that a 0 for all the odd observations and 1 for all the even observations, then we are done. As @NickCox noted in his answer such a function is `!mod(_n,2)`

Having said that, Nick's two line solution

```
gen u = rnormal()
replace u = u + 1 if mod(_n, 2) == 0
```

may be easier to read. That would be a very good reason for choosing Nick's solution.

Comment: `gen u = !mod(_n, 2) + rnormal()` is yet another way to do it. However, I suspect the OP's question was more general than their example!