# Stata Forvalues

Tags: for-loop, stata

This is my Code:

```
drop _all
set obs 50

forvalues k = 1/2 {
gen b`k' = .
}

forvalues i=1/1000 {
gen u = rnormal()
gen d = rnormal()


forvalues j = 1/2 {
quietly replace b`j' =  mean(u)  in `i' 
quietly replace b`j' =  mean(d)  in `i' 

}
drop u d
}

forvalues l = 1/6 {
su b`l'
}
hist b1
```

If I set obs = 50, it doesn’t work. The error is

> Obs. nos. out of range

If I set obs > 1000 it works fine.

What is wrong?

Comment: Please consider changing the title of your question to something more meaningful.

Comment: _Visible_ feedback from you is still pending in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783837/stata-elements-of-variable). Consider this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 1):

Posting code as you have done is great and most of the time required here in Stack Overflow. But a verbal, accompanying explanation, does no harm; quite the contrary, it can be very helpful.

I'm thrown off by the error you cite. The first error I receive upon running that code is

> unknown function mean() 
>   r(133);

So a good practice is posting your **exact** input and output as Stata displays it in the results window, and citing the source of installed user-written commands if any.

My guess is you're trying to do some simulation exercise. Specifically, you want the means of two random variables with 50 observations each, and you want to compute those means 1000 times. At the end, your result contains two variables (`b1` and `b2`) with 1000 observations each. Each observation is a mean. The command that may interest you is `postfile`. You'll want to look at the manual: **[P] postfile**, where the help is comprehensive.

```
clear all
set more off

set seed 2368056

*----- compute means -----

tempname memhold
tempfile results

postfile `memhold' b1 b2 using `results'
quietly forvalues i = 1/1000 {

    set obs 50

    gen u = rnormal()
    gen d = rnormal()

    summarize u, meanonly
    scalar mu = r(mean)

    summarize d, meanonly
    scalar md = r(mean)

    post `memhold' (mu) (md)

    drop _all
}

postclose `memhold'

*----- check final results -----

use `results', clear
list
```

The command `summarize` will give you the means in the form of stored results (see `help stored results`).
Notice also that `set obs 50` sets the number of observations for variables `u` and `d` at 50. But the number of loops (1000) is what controls the size of the final result. `post` will collect the computed means in a *different dataset*. When you're done, you can load the resulting file with `use`.

See: [www.stata.com/manuals13/ppostfile.pdf](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/ppostfile.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

@Roberto Ferrer has identified several problems with your code. Here are some more.

In this loop

```
forvalues j = 1/2 {
    quietly replace b`j' =  mean(u)  in `i' 
    quietly replace b`j' =  mean(d)  in `i' 
}
```

the first statement is futile, as the second overwrites what was just done. At a guess what you want is not a loop at all, but

```
   su u, meanonly 
   quietly replace b1 = r(mean) in `i' 
   su d, meanonly  
   quietly replace b2 = r(mean) in `i'
```

In this loop

```
forvalues l = 1/6 {
    su b`l'
}
```

there is no point in asking Stata to `summarize` the variables `b3` ... `b6` as they do not exist.